# Surface 3D modelling with meshing

Tags: windows, 3d, geometry

I'm looking for a software (or lib with python bindings) to generate quality tet/quad mesh in an easy to use toolchain, for input in a FEM solver. The operating system is Windows.

The capabilities needed:

1. Modeling 3D surfaces. Mostly planes and basic surfaces of revolution. Cylinder, torus, sphere and combinations of these. Free
   surfaces (as in NURBS) are not a necessity.
2. Calculation of the intersections of these.
3. Exporting the geometry for some free tetmesher for meshing, or
4. Meshing said surfaces, exporting the meshes (coordinates, topology), in some easy-to-parse format.

The software should be actively maintained - I want to use it for quite some years. I have currently Grasshopper3D and Sketchup in sight, both of which look great, but seem to be kind of an overshot. However, I have not tried these yet.

Edit: some example pics are here (the pics with the solid models are not relevant): [VisualFEA Preprocessor](http://www.visualfea.com/preprocessing.htm)

Comment: [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) should be able to do that. It has some export formats which are standardized, e.g. OBJ. "Easy to use toolchain" is hard to quantize, though. You can use Python as a programming language.

Comment: Thanks, Blender sounds great, especially that its free. As of easy to use: this was rather a thought for myself - easy for ME to use.